# Generating JsonSchema from pojo: how do I add "description" automatically?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I am trying to automatically generate JsonSchema from pojos in my project:  The code looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(clazz, visitor);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
String schemaString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema);
```

When clazz is defined like this:

```
public class ZKBean
{
  public String anExample;
  public int anInt;
}

I end up with this:

{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:emc:dpad:util:ZKBean",
  "properties" : {
    "anInt" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    "anExample" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

All that is great.  What I want to do is add the "description" key to the schema, so that I instead have something that looks like:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:emc:dpad:util:ZKBean",
  "properties" : {
    "anInt" : {
      "type" : "integer",
      "description" : "Represents the number of foos in the system"
    },
    "anExample" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Some descriptive description goes here"
    }
  }
}
```

I assumed there was some annotation I could just put on the fields in my ZKBean class, but after half a day of futzing I have not found one.  Is this the way to go?  Or do I need to do something with my Visitor?

Thanks,
Jesse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `@JsonPropertyDescription` annotation for generating json schema which works since Jackson 2.4.1. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonSchema {
    public static class ZKBean {
        @JsonPropertyDescription("This is a property description")
        public String anExample;
        public int anInt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
        mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(ZKBean.class, visitor);
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
        System.out.println(mapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:stackoverflow:JacksonSchema:ZKBean",
  "properties" : {
    "anExample" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "This is a property description"
    },
    "anInt" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason it doesn't work for me;  the annotation simply gets ignored.  Were you able to make it work, and does ZKBean being a static inner class matter?  I found this:   https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/pull/13   Which seems to indicate the jackson-module-jsonSchema could still have a bug.  Edit:  trying it out as an inner static class didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It appears that the functionality to support @JsonPropertyDescription has not yet been added to the jackson-module-jsonSchema project.   https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/issues/37

Comment: I am using 2.4.1 of everything (jackson-annotations, jackson-core, jackson-databind, jackson-module-jsonSchema), but the behavior I am seeing is still the @JsonPropertyDescription getting ignored.  Is there anything else I might try to get it working?

Comment: Hmm, I have created an example project https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/stackoverflow . Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes this now works for me;  the problem was that my class files were missing the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem lies not in the jackson libraries, but in the package I am using to generate the class objects.  My code is pasted below;  I suspect the Reflections object is dropping the annotation information (when I manually specify ZKBean.class the description appears).  Thanks for the help!

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
        new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(
            ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(urlcl)).
            addClassLoader(urlcl));
    Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(JsonBean.class);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    for (Class<?> clazz : annotated)
    {
      try
      {
        mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(mapper.constructType(SampleBean.class), visitor);
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
        String schemaString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema);
        System.out.println(schemaString);
```

Comment: Correction:  The Reflections package is likely not to blame.  For some reason the classes in my jar file are not retaining their annotations.

Comment: I'm glad that you finally solve this! I'd like to ask you to accept my answer so other people will know that property descriptions actually works since 2.4.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and identified another possible cause (just adding in hope this might help someone).

I am also loading Class objects (of DTO POJOs with Jackson annotations) using a custom ClassLoader and have them processed by ObjectMapper and SchemaFactoryWrapper to generate corresponding JSON schemas. In my case I forgot to add the jackson-annotations jar to the ClassLoader which leads to the described problem.